# MalformedURLException when using XmlSlurper

Tags: html, xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I have following code snippet in groovy:

```
s = '''
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
This is body!
</body>
</html>'''

new XmlSlurper().parse(s)
```

It gives following exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
This is body!
</body>
</html>
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:147)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:213)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at ConsoleScript12.run(ConsoleScript12:11)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:257)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:481)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:163)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy:955)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
This is body!
</body>
</html>
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at ConsoleScript12.run(ConsoleScript12:11)
```

**Why should there be a `MalformedURLException` when parsing XML?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you are parsing a String, you need to do:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText(s)
```

Instead of:

```
new XmlSlurper().parse(s)
```

[Groovydocs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#parse(java.lang.String)):

> **GPathResult parse(String uri)**: Parse the content of the specified URI
>   into a GPathResult Object.

Comment: Was wondering why ".parse()" was working.  I was giving it a File object, which makes sense (treats as a local URL).   Which it was named parseURI or similar.  Thanks!